# AngularFire2 (@angular/fire) How to get error from callable function?

Tags: typescript, error-handling, google-cloud-functions, angularfire2, angularfire

I'm trying to access a callable function's error message within an Angular environment using the angular fire package. Please see the following code:

*Angular (Client-Side)*

```
async myCallableFunction(id: string) {
  try {
    const res = await this.afFunctions.httpsCallable('callableFunction')({
      id
    }).toPromise();

    console.log(res);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error is:', err);
  }
}
```

*Server Side (Firebase Function)*

```
exports.callableFunction = functions.https.onCall((data: {
 id: string
}, context: https.CallableContext) => {
  // throw error for testing only
  throw new https.HttpsError('unknown', 'Test Error Message');
});
```

And the error message logged to the console is:

> [console.error]: "Error is:" { "code": "unknown", 
>   "line": 100205, "column": 32, "sourceURL":
>   "http://192.168.1.100:8100/vendor.js" }

How do I access the **error message** from the response by Cloud Firestore?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have just been stuck with this question in the past hour so I'll post my answer for those wandering here :

```
console.error('Error is:', err);
```

is not displaying the whole content of the err object.
If you want to access any of the 3 parameters if the err object you will have to access them directly :

```
  console.error(e.code);
  console.error(e.message);
  console.error(e.details);
```